# How to write a variable with a subscript

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How do you write something like the variable underlined in red in LaTex? The example I found looks something like this: `$\d{A}\d{0}$`, but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: You can upload images by pressing Ctrl+G when the focus is on the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get subscripts in maths mode with `_{<stuff>}`, so to get an A with a subscript zero you'd type `$A_{0}$`.

Comment: Not quite. I want to replicate the variable underlined in red (without the underline) if that makes any sense. Like, just Ao.

Comment: Well, then show what you want. The site has an upload function for pictures, I'm not going to click on arbitrary links :)

Comment: @FaithAlone if it's really just about subscripts I suggest reading a LaTeX introduction (every beginners guide should cover this). One viable introduction would be [LearnLaTeX](https://www.learnlatex.org/).

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: +1. I would recommend deleting the "original answer" part, though.